# MongoDB can't create 'change stream' (java)

Tags: database, mongodb, observer-pattern

I'm trying to get real-time updates from MongoDB. I used the changes stream API (from [here](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/driver/tutorials/change-streams/)). This is my code:

```
collection.watch().forEach(do_somthing);
```

But it just throws this error:

```
The $changeStream stage is only supported on replica sets
```

What is the meaning of `replica sets`? How can I manage to fix this problem?

This is the first time I'm using MongoDB...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A [replica set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/) is a group of MongoDB processes that maintain the data set. Replica Sets replicate data by creating a special collection called the [oplog](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/) which records all modifications to the data.

Change streams work by reading the oplog, so they require that your deployment are configured as a replica set.

See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/ for a guide on deployment a replica set.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple local test you can run your mongodb like that

```
mongod --dbpath=d:\data --oplogSize 50 --replSet rs0
```